# Negative Look Ahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Consider two `printk` kind of function calls -

```
TRACE_BR(TRACE ,    "END. rc = %d\n", rc );

TRACE_BR(TRACE, "Value = %s", string );
```

I am writing a regex to match whole function calls like the above which have `%` inside the string argument inside them, but should NOT match if the string `END` is also inside.

I used negative lookahead like this

```
TRACE_BR\(TRACE.*?(?!END)%.*
```

I expect this regex to match only the second function call, but its matching the first one too.

I guess I am going wrong somewhere with the greedy `*` part.

Comment: `TRACE_BR\(TRACE(?!.*END).*?%.*` I'm not entirely sure about your requirement, but the regex I posted will discard any line with END substring appearing after TRACE.

Comment: @nhahtdh your regex seems to be satisfying my requirement. But Why isn't mine working? You can post your comment as an answer and add your elaboration there. I am pretty confused when it comes to look-arounds

Comment: It does not work because TRACE.*?(?!END)% consumes the input until the %. The negative lookahead checks from position right before the %, and since there is no END at that position, the regex matches. That's why you need .* in your negative lookahead and have the external .* after it as suggested by @PavanManjunath.

Comment: @ZólyomiIstván Why is it consuming till `%`, when there is a negative lookahead even before `%`? Doesn't the engine stop as soon as it finds the string inside the lookahead?

Comment: @PavanManjunath: The regex engine may or may not consume until `%` depending on input, but logically, the `%` acts as some sort of "anchor" that restrict the possibility of a string that matches the regex: for the string to match the whole regex, the string must contain `%` at some point. And right before that point, you do a negative assertion, which is totally useless since it will always be true if the next character is `%`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The regex should be:

```
TRACE_BR\(TRACE(?!.*END).*?%.*
```

This regex will not match the line if `END` is a substring appearing after `TRACE`. You may need to modify the regex if you want a more refined matching.

You can think of the regex as: after I matched `TRACE` (and etc. in front), from the current position, I would like to look ahead that I cannot find `END` substring.

In your regex, if the character after the negative look-ahead assertion is `%`, the assertion is always true as `END` substring can't start there; if the character after the negative look-ahead assertion is not `%`, the regex will fail to match and backtrack.

In the hypothetical case that you remove the `%`, the regex will still allow a string with END to pass, since the sequence of any character `.*?` will allow the negative look ahead to match at any position along the way, and it can just find a position that is not the start of the string `END` and match it.